# Prove that $az^n+b\overline{z}^n=0$ does not have any complex solutions except for $0$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that $az^n+b\overline{z}^n=0$ when $|a|\ne|b|$ and $n\in\mathbb{N_1}$does not have any complex solutions except for $0$. What happens if $n\in\mathbb{C}$?

The first one seems very obvious, but is there any way to show it very formally?

Comment: "seems very obvious" is unfortunately not accepted as a proof.  Can you do the case $n=1$?  Is the general case reducible to that case?

Comment: So when $az+b\overline{z}=0$ the following equations need to be satisfied: $a Re z = -b Re z$ and $a Im z = b Im z$... So $Re z=0$ and $Im z=0$. Thus $z=0$?

Comment: Since you're given a condition on $|a|$ and $|b|$, try rearranging the question and then taking the magnitude/norm/length of both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $a z^{2n} = -b |z|^{2n}$. We can assume $a \neq 0$.

If $z \neq 0$, then ${z^{2n} \over |z|^{2n}} = -{b \over a}$. Then left hand side has unit length, then right hand side $|{ b \over a}| \neq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$az^n+b\overline z^n=0\implies az^{2n}+b|z|^{2n}=0$$

Suppose $\;z=re^{it}\;,\;\;r\in\Bbb R^+\;,\;\;t\in[0,2\pi]\;$ , then the above is

$$0=ar^{2n}e^{2nit}+br^{2n}\stackrel{\text{de Moivre}}= r^{2n}\left[\left(a\cos2nt+b\right)+ai\sin 2nt\right]\implies$$

$$\begin{cases}a\cos2nt+b=0\\{}\\a\sin2nt=0\end{cases}$$

The second equation already yields $\;\sin2nt=0\iff 2nt=k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ (as $\;a=0\;$ yields a trivial case and we assume $\;r>0\;$), and then the first equation gives

$$\pm a+b=0\;\implies\;|a|=|b|\implies\;\;\text{contradiction}$$

Answer (score 1):

$z=|z|e^{i\theta}$. Then $az^n+b\overline {z}^n=|z|(ae^{in\theta}+be^{-in\theta})$. If $z\neq 0$ then $|z|\neq 0$ and so we must have $ae^{in\theta}+be^{-in\theta}=0$. Because $|a| \neq |b|$ we can suppose that $|a|\neq 0$ and thus $ae^{in\theta}+be^{-in\theta}=0\Leftrightarrow  \frac {-b}{a}e^{-2in\theta} =1 \Rightarrow |\frac {-b}{a}e^{-2in\theta}| =1\Rightarrow |b|=|a| $

Comment: I made it more complicated than it should. Copper.hat's is the right one!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By switching $z$ and $\bar{z}$ if necessary, we may assume that $a \neq 0$. Multiply the equation by $z^n$ to get
$a z^{2n} + b |z|^{2n} = 0$, so that 
$z = |z| \omega$ for some $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ with the property that $\omega^{2n} = -b/a$.

Now can you see that $|\omega| \neq 1$? (hint: look at $|\omega|^{2n} = |\omega^{2n}|$). This should complete the proof.

For the case $n \in \mathbb{C}$, the same idea works, although you may be more comfortable solving the equation $z^{2n} = (-b/a)|z|^{2n}$ after making the transformation $z^n = \exp(n \log(z))$.